# When to use requestAnimationFrame to when altering element style with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

I have event handler for a click on `DOM element` that does CSS transition by messing with `DOM element` `style` property.

**Code Example A**

```
function toggleElement(isExpanded, element) {
  element.style.transition = 'opacity 500ms';
  element.style.opacity = isExpanded ? 0 : 1;
}
```

I can image that instead of simply writing `element.style.opacity = isExpanded ? 0 : 1;` I can wrap it into `requestAnimationFrame` function call:

**Code example B**

```
function toggleElement(isExpanded, element) {
  element.style.transition = 'opacity 500ms';
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    element.style.opacity = isExpanded ? 0 : 1;
  })
}
```

**Question: What is the difference between using code example A and Code example B?**

**My understanding:**

I assume I should wrap all `element.style` alterations inside `requestAnimationFrame`, so they are executed at the next good for browser moment, not instantly. Thus they will be definitely visible to user. And if I need to make something not visible (or as close to invisible as possible) I wouldn't use `requestAnimationFrame` method, do some raw `element.style` alterations e.g. to calculate element properties during effect of other styles and bring it back to default/initial/ state.

**P.S.** I have a use case where I actually need to do something like this in JS, otherwise just use CSS.

Comment: The difference is that there will be a slight delay in your second code, but not that much of a delay. it will wait till the next time browser is going to re-render things. but it is probably not what you want. it is going to trigger right away, not until the transition is finished

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI There is no difference between these two snippets in terms of the end result. since JS engine will wait for all the mutations and then does the repaint